# How to make a list of buttons dynamically and show them in the ItemsControl

Tags: wpf

I have a list of products that I need to load in buttons, but I can not get the buttons to appear.

code xaml:

```
 <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Productos}" Grid.Row="4"  Grid.Column="1" >
            <ItemsControl.Resources>
                <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:SeleccionarOpcionesCotizacionesView2}">
                    <Button Command="{Binding CmdCuenta}" Style="{StaticResource TransparentStyle}"  Width="775" Height="157"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.Resources>

        </ItemsControl>
```

picture of how the list is displayed (buttons should appear):

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fy0vm.png)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26488934/add-items-to-itemscontrol

Comment: Make sure that Productos is a public property in the DataContext of your view. Instead of adding the DataTemplate to the ItemsControl's Resources, you may directly assign it to the ItemTemplate property, and omit the DataType.

Comment: How and where is the `Productos` property that you are binding to defined?

Answer (score 2):

Check the following:

• Make sure your property named "Productos" is public.

• Make sure you're using an collection type of "ObservableCollection"

• If you're using the MVVM pattern and your property is in a model class, make sure your model is set to the context of the view.

```
 MyViewModel model = new MyViewModel();
 this.DataContext = model;
```

• Make sure the ItemsControl is actually visible. Set height and width to fix value for testing purposes.

• If your not using MVVM and your property named "Productos" is in the partial class of the view, make sure to set the binding on the partial class. To do this give your control/view a name and set the binding directly on the view control element.

```
<UserControl x:Name="Control_View" />


<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Path=OpenUserProfileEditor, ElementName=Control_View}" />
```

Alos, try making your ItemsControl like mine below. (Example)

```
  <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Productos}" Grid.Row="4"  Grid.Column="1" >
            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
               <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:SeleccionarOpcionesCotizacionesView2}">
                   <Button Command="{Binding CmdCuenta}" Style="{StaticResource TransparentStyle}"  Width="775" Height="157"/>
               </DataTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
   </ItemsControl>
```

Comment: Unless the command really is a property of the data item, it should be bound using a relative source to the main viewmodel (ItemsControl.DataContext).